# Explanation needed (UITableView, NSMutableSet)

Tags: uitableview, nsmutableset

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableSet*selectedRows;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

...

```
self.selectedRows = [NSMutableSet new];
```

...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
    }else{
        [self.selectedRows removeAllObjects];//test 1 item only
        [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath %@ \nSelected %@", indexPath,self.selectedRows);
    for (NSIndexPath*item in self.selectedRows) {
        if ([item compare:indexPath]==NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"EXIST1");
        }        
        if (item.section == indexPath.section && item.row == indexPath.row) {
            NSLog(@"EXIST2");
        }
    }

    if ([self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"EXIST3");
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
```

After redrawing cells I expect filter selected cell.

The question is why I get only this in log:
EXIST1
EXIST2

where is EXIST3?

simple test:

```
NSMutableSet*s =[NSMutableSet new];

NSIndexPath*p1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
NSIndexPath*p2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];

NSComparisonResult r1= [p1 compare:p2];

NSLog(@"p1 compare p2 = %@", r1==NSOrderedSame?@"YES":@"NO" );

[s addObject:p1];

NSLog(@"contain p1 =%@", [s containsObject:p1]==YES?@"YES":@"NO" );
NSLog(@"contain p2 =%@", [s containsObject:p2]==YES?@"YES":@"NO" );
NSLog(@"s = %@",s);
```

result

```
2014-01-08 04:42:57.477 test[28342:70b] p1 compare p2 = YES
2014-01-08 04:42:57.478 test[28342:70b] contain p1 =YES
2014-01-08 04:42:57.478 test[28342:70b] contain p2 =YES
2014-01-08 04:42:57.479 test[28342:70b] s = {(
    <NSIndexPath: 0x8b2e0d0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 1}
)}
```

Comment: I think the difference between -containsObject and -compare is that -containsObject: looks for exactly the SAME object and -compare compares the content of the objects. Because in your case the content of the objects is identical, but not the object itself.

Comment: in this case in test [s containsObject:p2] should return NO

Comment: No, because in your test case the compiler optimizes your code and sets p1 and p2 to the same object, because both of them are statically allocated with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

small NSIndexPath category fix

```
@interface NSIndexPath (Extended)
-(NSUInteger)hash;
@end


@implementation NSIndexPath (Extended)
-(NSUInteger)hash{
    char str[11];
    int row = self.row;
    int section = self.section;
    sprintf(str, "%d%d", section,row);

    unsigned int val = 0;
    char *p;
    int i;
    p = str;
    for(i = 0; p[ i ]; i++){
        if (i ==0) {
            val = (unsigned char)p[i] << CHAR_BIT;
        }
        else
            val |= (unsigned char)p[i];
    }
    return val;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by filtering the set. I'm not sure which is more efficient, but this was performant enough for my purposes.
code is from a call to heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSSet * set = [self.hiddenPaths filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section == %u AND row == %u",indexPath.section, indexPath.row]];

if (![set count])
{
  return 0.0f;//cell at indexPath is hidden
}
```